# Webpy Template Function syntax

Tags: templates, syntax, web.py

I am trying to write a web application using Webpy. My application gets info on outputs that are ether off or on. I would like to use an image to show an "on" button or an "off" button. 
The data sent to the Webpy template is a dictionary of outputs (key defines the output) and a value (in String type) the value is either '1' for on or '0' for off.
My first thought was to write a function within my template to return the image file based on the value like this:

template_tester_simple.py:

```
import web
render = web.template.render('templates/')
urls = ('/', 'index')
template_tester_simple = web.application(urls, globals())


class index: 
    def GET(self):
        return render.test_func(data)


def add_data():
    data = {'currSet':'75','currTemp':'60','currMode':'Off',
'Cool':'1', 'Heat':'1', 'RevValve':'1', 'EmHeat':'1','Fan':'1',}            
    return data        

data = add_data()
if __name__=="__main__":
    web.internalerror = web.debugerror
    template_tester_simple.run()
```

and My test_func.html template:

```
$def with (data)

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    $code:
        def getSwitchImg(item):
            x=""
        if (item=='1'):
            x="<img src= '../static/switch_on.png'></img>"
        else: "<img src= '../static/switch_off.png'></img>"
        return x

<body>
        <ul>
                <li><strong>Cooling</strong><p>
                $getSwitchImg($data['Cool'])
                </p></li>
                            <li><strong>Reversing Valve</strong><p>
                $getSwitchImg($data['RevValve'])
                </p></li>

        </ul>
</body>
```

This returns a Syntax Error as:

at /
invalid syntax Template traceback: File 'templates/test_func.html', line 23 None (test_func.html, line 23)

I could not figure out the Syntax error. It lists a line that is the closing tag of my unordered list , which does not make any sense since it is past all the python code. So It must be something in WebPy template system that I do not understand. Is the function block not getting "closed" properly? 
Out of frustration, I then changed my template to the following, using the same template_tester_simple.py:

```
$def with (data)

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Cooling</strong>
            $if data['Cool'] == '1':
                <img src="../static/switch_on.png" height="15px" width="40px"></img>
            $else:
                <img src="../static/switch_off.png" height="15px" width="40px"></img>
          </li>
            <li><strong>Heating</strong>
            $if data['Heat'] == '1':
                <img src="../static/switch_on.png" height="15px" width="40px"></img>
            $else:
                <img src="../static/switch_off.png" height="15px" width="40px"></img>
          </li>
           </ul>
        </body>
```

This works, but I am not defining the function I wanted to use. I am forced to copy/paste basically the same code over and over. As I develop this project further, I plan to add more switches, therefore more digital outputs. If I could get the first template code to work, it will make expanding my app much easier. Also I want to understand the syntax associated with functions within WebPy templates. I have read the templator tutorial on the Webpy website. I thought that once you used "code:" you went to standard python syntax, then once you come out of the indented block, it should be standard HTML. Could someone please explain this syntax, and therefore my error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's just the way you copy/paste your code here but I've seen an indention problem here.

```
    def getSwitchImg(item):
        x=""
    if (item=='1'):
        x="<img src= '../static/switch_on.png'></img>"
    else: "<img src= '../static/switch_off.png'></img>"
    return x
```

It's supposed to be:

```
    def getSwitchImg(item):
        x=""
        if (item=='1'):
           x="<img src= '../static/switch_on.png'></img>"
        else: 
           x="<img src= '../static/switch_off.png'></img>"
        return x
```